# cx-carousal next and previous control CTA

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am using Spartacus 4.3 and using the "ProductReferenceComponent" to display cross-selling products. I want to add some addition functionality when user clicks on the next or previous ICONs. Basically I need to dynamically add/remove class on click on the previous/next slides in cx-carousal.
How do I call a function/event on previous/next slides in cx-carousal.